# Textblock in Viewbox not multiline

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, viewbox

I'm having a bit of a trouble with the autosizing of a text. I read somewhere that if I wanted to achieve that, i need to put my *textblock* in a *viewbox*. The problem with that is this way the text isn't split into multiple lines. For example "very very very long text" is almost unreadable, but "simpletext" looks just fine.

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
     <TextBlock 
         Text="{Binding FieldName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Nueva Std" />
</Viewbox>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set a width (or max width) on the TextBlock.

Comment: And how can i set the maxwidth to be equivalent with the specific cell's width?

Comment: I'd set it to be, let's say, two times bigger than width of Viewbox using something like `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource MultiplyByTwoConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`. If you set it to be cell's width, there would be no scaling at all.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't end up quite well. Somewhere it's fine, somewhere it's even smaller than before.

Comment: Accepted your answer because i set the MaxWidth and i used a FieldNameConverter to replace whitespaces with new lines where needed. That makes kinda a mixture of your answers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to your textblock TextWrapping="Wrap" - wrapping IsHyphenationEnabled="True" - breaking the word with hyphen

Comment: Didn't work. Now "simpletext" look like
simpletex\n
t

Answer (score 0):

In this case, here is another solution: take [this class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ViewBox.cs,22e476b746489c42) and make your own LimitedViewbox version, which will have some LowerStretchLimit property. I think it should work.